# sftp Bad Ownership of Home Directory

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

When trying to connect to sftp, I get the error in auth.log

> sshd[53217]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory "/home/cclloyd"

When using the following sshd config

```
Match group verified-users
        ChrootDirectory %h
        ForceCommand internal-sftp -d %d
```

But I look at the directory and it appears fine.

```
total 16K
drwxr-xr-x  4 root      root      4.0K May  2 11:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 20 root      root      4.0K May  2 14:18 ..
drwxr-x--- 11 cclloyd   cclloyd   4.0K May  4 12:14 cclloyd
```

So far, it's only worked when the owner of my user folder is `root`, which won't work as I won't have write permissions anymore.

So what isn't right that I can't set the home directory to the chroot?